# How variable different from the reference?

Tags: php

What is a variable?

What is a reference?

How variable different from the reference?

For example we have the next code:

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$b = 100;
echo "\$a = ",$a,"\n\$b = ",$b;
```

What's in this code will be a reference, variable and why?

P.S Do not write me please, "Read manual". I read the manual, and if I got answers there that I would not have asked the question here

Comment: When you add the reference then those variables are depended to each other, It means if you change one variable value then The address also changes the other value or assign with the new value. At the end the `&`  always track these variables, so that there value always same in the function or area.

Comment: @fragilewindows That's C++. This is PHP. Not the same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generally

In programming, a variable or scalar is a **storage location** paired with an **associated symbolic name** (an identifier), which contains some known or unknown quantity of information referred to as a value.

A **reference** is a value that enables a program to **indirectly access** a particular datum, such as a variable or a record, in the computer's memory or in some other storage device. The reference is said to refer to the datum, and **accessing the datum** is called **dereferencing** the reference.

---

### In PHP (based on what you've asked)

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
echo $b;
```

Resulting in:

```
10
```

$a is a variable $b is a reference to the $a variable, means that $a and $b both of them access the same value in the memory, so if you print $b you'll see 10.

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$b = 100;
echo $a;
```

Resulting in:

```
100
```

In that case instead what you'll have is something different, the fact that you're changing the value of $b (which is a **reference** of $a) to 100 affects the value that $a holds as well, so if you print $a here you'll se that it's value is actually 100 and not 10.

Hope to be clear.

Comment: I think you have enough explanation for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the reference then those variables are depended to each other, It means if you change one variable value then The address also changes the other value or assign with the new value. At the end the & always track these variables, so that there value always same in the function or area.

**From the manual:**
References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual memory addresses, and so on. See What References Are Not for more information. Instead, they are symbol table aliases. Note that in PHP, variable name and variable content are different, so the same content can have different names. The closest analogy is with Unix filenames and files - variable names are directory entries, while variable content is the file itself. References can be likened to hardlinking in Unix filesystem.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: reference = variable, is it true or not?

Comment: what do you mean by `reference = variable`??

Comment: @MaximPro technically it is a variable, but that variable does not hold a value, it holds a reference, holds a anchor let say to the referenced variable

Comment: @Cristian And then what will happen if we make reference to the value of some variable and then delete the variable that is referenced?
Example `$a = 0; $b = &$a; $a = 100; unset($a);` $b - variable or reference?(before referenced and after)?

Comment: unset() destroys the specified variables. So unset($a) will destroy what is referenced by $a, but what is referenced by $a is also referenced by $b. So before the unset() $b will print 100 after the unset() $b will print noting as well as $a

Comment: @Cristian http://ideone.com/iT5SIl - after the unset() $b will print noting (its lie! check the code)

Comment: Yes sorry i was printing the wrong variable in my code I have now checked and its $b actually prints 100.

Comment: So eventually unset() just erases the reference to whatever area of memory that the variable has

Comment: @Cristian So reference = variable, is it true or not? I can not understand!
$b - variable or reference?

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nxY39B3nwuY/VflqSpvwaSI/AAAAAAAADxE/jh6P6bj_oLQ/s1600/Difference%2Bbetween%2Breference%2Band%2Bprimitive%2Bvariable%2Bin%2BJava.gif take a look here, on the top you see variables on the bottom references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125798/discussion-between-cristian-and-maximpro).